# Maya – Convert regular camera to "camera and aim group"

Tags: python, camera, maya, mel

I want to convert a normal moving camera to a `camera and aim` group.

How can I do it? Using API, matrix, etc? Is there a formula？

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The Maya `camera and aim` option on the `Create` menu runs a Mel script that has a few of operations in it. As a simplified version of that, you can use the Python Maya command `cmds.aimConstraint` to constraint the `z` vector to a locator to get a similar result.

Below is a Python script that does something similar to that Mel script. I'm creating a new camera here, but you can constraint your existing camera to a new locator.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

# Create a locator at the center of the world
locator = cmds.spaceLocator()

# Create a camera
cam_shape, camera = cmds.camera()

# Point the camera at the locator
cmds.aimConstraint(locator, cam_shape, aimVector=[0, 0, -1])

# move the camera back 3 units
cmds.move(0, 0, 3, camera)
```

With that, the camera will always point to the locator in a similar fashion that the `Camera and Aim` menu option does.

You can now animate (or move) that camera and it will always point to the locator.